# composer php not found centos

Tags: php, composer-php, installation

I am new to CentOS and I am trying to install composer through the terminal. Unforently it keeps saying file not found.

My terminal command as root:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/install | php
```

and the output error is

```
bash: php: command not found

curl: (23) Failed writing body ( 0 !=7626)
```

have things changed with composer and the install process for centos or am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to install PHP first before you can install composer.
Installing PHP with yum package management:

```
yum install php
```

Comment: thank you for that. don't know how I missed that info.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install PHP first on centos then you will be able to run your command

Answer (score 0):

First, install php & php-cli

```
yum install php
yum install php-cli
```

and then run composer install

[**Read this article too**](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-centos-6)